# ARM64 hooking: insert a jump in memory

Tags: android, assembly, memory, hook, arm64

I'm trying to hook on a 64 bit ARM Android device the SSL_do_handshake function available in libssl.so, until now I have:

- address of libssl.so (found in proc//maps)
- offset of SSL_do_handshake(found in libssl.so)
- absolute address of SSL_do_handshake (address_of_libssl + offset_of_SSL_do_handshake)

What I'm doing is save the instructions at absolute address of libssl.so (for recovery) and overwrite them with my instructions (for jump):

- LDR X9,#8
- Br X9
- address for jump 7f75a5b890

In detail what I'm saving in memory is 49000058 20011fd6 90b8a5757f if I look in memory after the overwriting I found my instructions and the address. If I try to execute it and call SSL_do_hanshake I have a crash before the jump. 
I did the same for ARMv7 using thumb32 with the same approach but different instructions:

- ldr pc [pc,#0]
- address for jump (f36e240d)

In memory dff800f0 0d246ef3 and it works.
Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I sure hope `LDR X9,#8 ` is a typo and it uses pc just like the armv7 does ;)